# Total angular momentum of an atom's electron in $s$-state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-spin

Consider it has zero orbital angular momentum, what is the total angular momentum?

what I thought is since orbital angular momentum is $0$, what left is the spin angular momentum, which is $\hbar/2$ or $-\hbar/2$, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the total angular momentum $\mathbf{J}=\mathbf{L}+\mathbf{S}$, if you consider a state where the orbital angular momentum is zero, then indeed what remains is the spin angular momentum, whose value projected on a given axis is either $\pm \hbar/2$ for an electron.

Answer (score 1):

One has to distinguish between *an atom* and *an electron in a centrally symmetric potential*. Atom contains a nucleus and electrons. Since the question implies an electron in an s-state, I suppose we are talking about a hydrogen atom or an ion with only one electron. Still, the total angular moment is that of the electron plus the angular moment of a nucleus. The nucleus of a hydrogen atom is just a proton with spin-1/2, so the atom has angular moment $1$ (with projections $0,\pm1$ on the quantization axis).

Comment: There is also the singlet state.

Comment: The question title explicitly singles out the atom's *electron*. Putting in the nucleus only serves to add confusion.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I didn't pay attention that it was specifically about the electron (or, possibly the title was edited). In this case however the question is incorrectly posed, since the orbital momentum does not belong to electron only.